# Argument type validation in the Function Wizard

Tags: excel, excel-dna, excel-udf

In Excel, the DATE function for example shows "=number" against each field.

If I enter a string in these fields in place of a number, I get the #VALUE! error.

Can similar functionality be achieved with Excel-DNA?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Excel supports a way to show those types for user-defined functions. [Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) registers functions with the right types (like taking a Double). Excel completely controls how things are displayed in the Function Arguments dialog, and some aspects only work for built-in functions, like having mandatory parameters (displayed in bold).